# Confusion regarding effects of changing any mass in Principle of Equilibrium of Mixtures/Principle of Calorimetry

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, equilibrium, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

My book says that a calorimeter is made of thin copper sheets, and the thinner the better since less mass means less heat capacity, which means for the same temperature change, less heat is required by the calorimeter... which is absorbed by the cooler substance in the mixture.

However the maths doesn't make sense to me this way:

Suppose there is a substance $B$ in calorimeter $C$, and they are at equilibrium temperature $T_B$. Now I pour a warmer substance of temperature $T_A$ into the calorimeter and they soon reach an equilibrium temperature of $T$. The equation can be written as then,

$$m_Ac_A(T_A-T)=(m_Bc_B+m_Cc_C)(T-T_B)$$

Now if I decrease $m_C$ as said in the book, $m_Bc_B(T-T_B)$ will increase to accommodate for the change as heat loss always equals heat gain. But $m_Bc_B$ is a constant, and in order to prove what the book has said we cannot change initial temperature as the experiment will be pointless then, so the only thing which can change is $T$.

- But if $T$ increases, then LHS decreases $\because$ it has $(T_A-T)$ as a factor.
- If we increase $T$, then $m_Cc_C$ is increasing again as it has $(T-T_B)$ as a factor.
- So that way I think it ends up being $m_Ac_A(T_A-T)<(m_Bc_B+m_Cc_C)(T-T_B)$, which is obviously not possible.

**So what actually happens when we decrease $m_C$? What changes take place in the system to accommodate with the fact that heat loss=heat gain?**

Comment: Here are some leading questions:  Algebraically, what do you get if you solve the equation for T?  What is the derivative of this with respect to $m_Cc_C$?

Comment: @ChetMiller I get $$T=\frac{(m_Bc_B+m_Cc_C)T_B + m_Ac_AT_A}{m_Ac_A+m_Bc_B+m_Cc_C}$$

Comment: And the answer to my other question is ...?

Comment: For the derivative of T with respect to $m_C$, I get $$-\frac{m_Ac_Ac_C}{(m_Ac_A+m_Bc_B+m_Cc_C)^2}(T_A-T_B)$$What does this tell you?

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm afraid I don't know what derivative is.P.S.: sorry for the late response, I've had a really busy day today

Comment: In this case, it is the rate of change of the temperature T with respect to the amount of mass mc.  It says that, if you decrease the amount of calorimeter mass and TA is greater than TB, the final temperature T will be higher.

Comment: So... does my problem make sense with maths I'm not familiar with, namely, derivative? @ChetMiller

Comment: The result makes sense to me.  Have you not had calculus yet?

Comment: @ChetMiller unfortunately, no. You can check my SE profile for my educational level, its there in my about section. I have calculus in my curriculum next year